# How to update a navigation collection property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I simply would like to update the customer and one of his orders using Entity Framework 6. I tried this but it is updating the customer only not his orders:

```
Customer customer = db.Cutomers.Include(x => x.Orders).Where(y => y.Id  ==1234).SingleOrDefault();
customer.Name = "Joe";              //  changing the customer name
customer.Orders[0].OrderDesc = "NewDesc";  //  changing one of the orders
customer.Orders[0].OrderDate = DateTime.Now;

using (var db = new Context())
{      
       db.Cutomers.Attach(customer);
       db.Entry(customer).Collection(e => e.Orders).Load();
       db.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;   
       db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are loading the `Orders` collection after making the changes so basically this is overriding the changes you previously made.
Since you are editing the `Order` you are going to have to `Attach` the order itself to the collection so that it is updated.

***EDIT***

```
db.Orders.Attach(customer.Orders[0]);
```

Comment: Ok. I understand that I should be loading from DB before I make the changes but the second part of your answer is not clear to me. How do I "Attach the order itself to the collection so that it is updated."

Comment: @user3237706 its hard to tell how you are loading your entity unless you post the code for the `GetCustomerFromDB` function. See my edit for what I mean about attaching.

Comment: I updated the code to show how I am getting the customer. I tried your suggestion, but I guess I am still missing something.

Comment: @user3237706 did you remove the `(e => e.Orders).Load()` part?

Comment: still there. I added this: Customer customer = db.Cutomers.Include(x => x.Orders).Where(y => y.Id  ==1234).SingleOrDefault();

Comment: Remove the `Load()` and try attaching the customer's order to the orders entity

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly attach the children.  It is better to do this yourself anyway, i'm sure you don't want every database call to automatically update the entire entity tree for each entity.